# getblocktemplate returns out of memory

Tags: mining-pools, altcoin, error, cli

I tried on a few different machines, vps etc. Also, few different altcoin litecoin included. Most were with 4 GB of ram, if this matters.

Every time when I enter the command getblocktemplate , I get return error message -7 "out of memory".

This prevents me from mining the coins in a pool.

Does anyone have any idea, why do I get these errors, and what to do to fix them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was the masternodes syncing.
Once I created a masternode and synced it, the getblocktemplate started returning normally.

Answer (score 0):

The error is exactly as it sounds: your machine was unable to allocate memory for the block template object thus it ran out of memory. You will need to use a machine that has more RAM.

Comment: I tried it ona a machine with 8GB of ram and still it returns the same error. Could it be, that the error indicates something else, or a blocktemplate could really take more than 8GB of space?

Comment: The block template is really not that large. There's probably something else going on in your OS that is preventing it from being able to allocate the memory.

Comment: Any idea what could that be? Some file permissions? Any other ideas?